# Deferred functions, Leaflet with GeoJSON

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I'm trying to chain functions, and I make a mistake somewhere, but I can't find where...

First, I create a new GeoJSON layer. It works.

`var dataLayer = L.geoJSON(null).addTo(myMap);`

Next I add some JSON data, it works too.

```
function getData() {
        var defer = $.Deferred();
        returnData = $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "JSON",
                url: myURL,                          // a normal URL
                error: function (x, e, s) {},        // handle error
                success: ,                           // empty
                complete: function (jqXHR, status) {
                                                     // some other stuff
                        dataLayer.addData(returnData.resopnseJSON);
                                                     // some other stuff
                        defer.resolve();
                        }
        });
        return defer.promise();
}
```

The AJAX query is quite long, about 50-100 ms. I'd like to chain the functions, because the next function should use the data added by `getData()`. In an other part of the code, when there is a lot of time (eg. some interaction, click from the user), `nextFunc()` can use the data added by `getData()`, so I'm quite sure, that the code of the functions are OK.

But if I'd like to call an other function immediately after `getData()` completed

`$.when(getData()).done(nextFunc());`

the `nextFunc()` function doesn't wait, it starts immediately after `getData()` started.

How can I force `nextFunc()` to wait until `getData()` is done?

Answer (score 3):

I'd just leave jQuery's `deferred`s behind and switch everything to `Promise`s and `fetch()`es.

```
function getData() {
  return fetch(myURL, { /* stuff for post */ })
    .then(function(response) { return response.json() })
    .then(function(json) { dataLayer.addData(json); })
    .catch(function(error) { /* handle errors if any */ }
}

getData().then(nextFunc);
```

Note it's `getData.then(nextFunc)` and **not** `getData.then(nextFunc())`. That would be the equivalent of `getData.then(/* return value of having executed nextFunc immediately */)`

Comment: Thanks. I can't figure out, in this case how to pass variables to `nextFunc`.